# Time series cross-validation removing new categories from test

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to use time series cross validation to evaluate my model. I'm trying to leverage *TimeSeriesSplit* and *cross_validate* from sklearn.

Let's say my model has features A, B, and others. In practice I want my model only to give predictions for categories A and B seen during training, for all other categories it will raise an error.

How I can cross validate my model enforcing this behaviour? Could I still use the sklearn implementations, adapt them with minor changes or would I have to build my cross validation from scracth?

Answer (score 0):

1. Import TimeSeriesSplit.
2. Then create an instance of TimeSeriesSplit (set the test size parameter to 1)
3. Then define a method, which filters out all the unwanted categories from the train and test dataset and outputs your filtered data.
4. Import cross_validate from scikit-learn, then make sure to call your custom function for every iteration of your cross_validate.

This way you can implement cross validation with minor changes rather than implementing it all from scartch.